# 'by which' vs 'by the which'

Tags: differences

[Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bQpPfTGYDjQC&dq=%22ensued%20by%22&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=%22ensued%20by%22&f=false): p 101, *Lives and letters of the Devereux, earls of Essex*, by Walter Bourchier Devereux

> [[p 100](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bQpPfTGYDjQC&dq=%22ensued%20by%22&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=%22ensued%20by%22&f=false) states that this letter was undated, but the penultimate sentence on p99 (ie the last sentence of the previous letter) contains 1575, so I think that this was the year.] No XVIII.’
>   The Queen to Essex.
>
> Right trusty and well beloved Cousin, greeting. Having
>   seen certain offers and requests made by you unto our Deputy
>   in your letter of the 15th of this present directed to our Council, **by the which** you do not only shew yourself providently
>   careful to avoid the inconvenience that might have ensued by
>   the sudden giving over or the enterprize for the reformation
>   of Ulster, but also, for the preventing of such mischiefs as
>   were likely to ensue thereby, was content to spoil yourself of
>   that reputation that birth and desert hath cast upon you,
>   offering to serve under our Deputy there in place not answerable to your state and calling; ...

What are the purposes of **the**? What are the similarities and differences?

Comment: You're asking us to analyze 16th century grammar; today the *"the"* would very likely be dropped.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. Actually, I wasn't sure whether this structure would be still used today, so I decided to ask lest it were.

Comment: See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+which&year_start=1560&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20which%3B%2Cc0). The use of *"by the which"* was already dropping by 1700, and it's practically nonexistent today.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I'll try to worry less about this then, but I'll await possible answers.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to say beyond what Peter has already said.

Comment: Although it looks hopelessly archaic in OP's *exact* context, I find it a bit more "normal" (just "starchy, dated") in certain other contexts. ***The which*** might include this sentence, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I personally find it easy to switch registers to include "the which" in moderation. Others' mileage may vary, but I suppose one can't always dumb things down for the least literate among us.

Answer (score 1):

*which* is [a relative pronoun with an animate or inanimate antecedent in Middle English](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=241863824&egdisplay=open&egs=241907275), where it appears as "which" or "the which". "The which" survived into Shakespeare's time but started to fall out of use by the mid 1600s.

> Þe bledder, þe braines, þe lyuer, þe reynes, þe hert, and þe midreffe
>   ben members þe whiche, ȝif þei be wounded, it is moste to drede.